# Does this question need to be flagged as too vague?

Tags: discussion, flags, specific-question

I am wondering if the following question should be flagged as too broad and vague.

[Unit Testing The Onion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498909/unit-testing-the-onion)

I see three questions in this post:

- "does this look like a standard way to unit test?"
- "Also, what about some thoughts on testing with my IoC (Ninject)?"
- "Any thoughts or advice would be very appreciated."

The second one is pretty open-ended. The poster doesn't ask about anything specific but for people to give out any thoughts they might have.

Again the last phrase of the question, seems to be an open call to discuss anything related to this question.

I considered flagging the question but the popup on flag mentions "flag this post for serious problems." I am not sure these qualify as serious problems by the community's standard.

Answer (score -2):

It's really more of a [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) question than a Stack Overflow question for sure.  You are correct in that it's not specific enough, it should be migrated to Programmers.

Unfortunately there's no direct migration path to Programmers via close votes, so I've flagged it instead of just voting to close.

Comment: The question is not suitable material for Programmers. If you are not active on the site, please don't suggest it as a migration target.

Comment: How is it not suitable?  It's about architecture and design patterns with respect to testing.

Comment: It's too vague. "Any thoughts or advice" - it's asking for a list of answers. The same "answerable and specific" rules apply on Programmers as on *any* site on the network.

Comment: It's a question that belongs on Programmers but needs improvement to remain open.  Migration to the appropriate site, then closure if it isn't good enough is a perfectly fine path.  Then if it gets improved, it's in the right spot.  At least on Programmers it has a chance.

Comment: I'm a moderator on Programmers - I've just closed it.

Comment: @DanielDiPaolo In general it's not appropriate to migrate a question if it's just going to be closed on the target site.  That is simply offloading questions you don't want to get to somewhere else.  Questions should only be migrated if they are clearly of value to the target site, not because they have negative value to the current site.  The proper action would be to close it (without migrating) and to have the OP re-ask the question on the target site *after improving the question enough to not be close worthy*.  It would also work to edit the question into good shape then migrate.